# Web Dev: Grid/Flex. It is only displaying one box in the top left corner

Tags: html, web, flexbox, grid

```css
body{
    background-color:#3D3D3D;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.NavBar{

    height:3em;

    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;


    background-color:#222222;
    border:black solid 1px;
}
.NavBar a{
    text-decoration: none;

    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: white;

    margin: 0.8% 1% 0.8% 1%;

    display: inline;
}

.container{
    display:grid;

    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 200px 600px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd"
    "sp ct ct ct ct ct ct sp"
    "ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft";


}
#HeaderBox{
    grid-area: hd;
}
#ContentBox{
    grid-area: ct;
}
#SidePanel{
    grid-area: sp;
}
#FooterBox{
    grid-area: ft;
    background-color:#222222;
    border:black solid 1px;
}

.box{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    border:black solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JG</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="NavBar">
            <a href="">Home</a>
            <a href="">About Me</a>
            <a href="">Blog</a>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="box" id="HeaderBox"><h1>Savage Boxers Of My Generation</h1></div>
            <div class="box" id="ContentBox"></div>
            <div class="box" id="SidePanel"></div>
            <div class="box" id="FooterBox"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The footer is somewhere off the webpage near the bottom right of the screen(extending off the screen starting near the center of the screen. Nothing is being displayed, although I am expecting to see a black border around each box, I have also tried changing the colour to white in case I might have missed it.

I am following a tutorial on Udacity and can not seem to find the problem. I have ID's and am
trying to complete the layout of my page by putting the ID into the grid layout. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've splitted the sidepanels to SidePanelLeft and SidePanelRight so that the grid-template-areas knows where to place them (the website inspector was complaining about the value of grid-template-areas).

Also added another value for grid-template-rows as there are three rows and the footer wasn't displayed once the previous problem was solved.

After this two changes your code works:

```css
body{
    background-color:#3D3D3D;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.NavBar{

    height:3em;

    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;


    background-color:#222222;
    border:black solid 1px;
}
.NavBar a{
    text-decoration: none;

    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: white;

    margin: 0.8% 1% 0.8% 1%;

    display: inline;
}

.container{
    display:grid;

    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 200px 600px 200px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd"
    "spl ct ct ct ct ct ct spr"
    "ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft";
}
#HeaderBox{
    grid-area: hd;
}
#ContentBox{
    grid-area: ct;
}
#SidePanelLeft{
    grid-area: spl;
}
#SidePanelRight{
    grid-area: spr;
}
#FooterBox{
    grid-area: ft;
    background-color:#222222;
    border:black solid 1px;
}

.box{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border:black solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JG</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="NavBar">
            <a href="">Home</a>
            <a href="">About Me</a>
            <a href="">Blog</a>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="box" id="HeaderBox"><h1>Savage Boxers Of My Generation</h1></div>
            <div class="box" id="SidePanelLeft"></div>
            <div class="box" id="ContentBox"></div>
            <div class="box" id="SidePanelRight"></div>
            <div class="box" id="FooterBox"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```